QSV hardware acceleration does not work with ffmpeg 7.0
I've been using Intel Quick Sync (QSV) hardware acceleration for several years with ffmpeg for decoding, encoding, and filtering.  I've been using only 4.4-full_build-www.gyan.dev on Windows 7 and 10 because when I looked at newer versions they were missing essential features for repairing videos that were less than perfect.
I am now trying 7.0-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev because it has access to improvements in hevc_qsv and h264_qsv codecs. But I can't get it to run at all with QSV because it won't initialize the device.
I've stripped down a test command to test this:
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel verbose ^
 -init_hw_device qsv=hw -hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_device qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv ^
 -i "InputFile.avi" ^
 -vsync vfr -c:a aac -profile:a aac_he -q:a 1.1 ^
 -vf "hwupload=extra_hw_frames=128,vpp_qsv=w=iw/2:h=ih/2" ^
 -c:v hevc_qsv -preset faster -y ^
 "F:\Convert\OutputFile.mp4"

This works perfectly with 4.4.  I normally use -init_hw_device qsv:hw,child_device_type=qsv to create a device but various sources say the simpler version will also work, and it does in 4.4; but 7.0 rejects that and will not create a child device.  The example I have given above also fails completely with 7.0, which tells me I should use "-init_hw_device qsv=hw" to create a device, when you can see that the command has one.
I have also tried various other versions I have found on the web or the ffmpeg web site documentation, including:
-init_hw_device qsv=qsv:MFX_IMPL_hw 
-init_hw_device qsv=qsv:MFX_IMPL_HARDWARE 
-init_hw_device qsv:hw,child_device=1
replacing qsv=hw with qsv=hw_auto or qsv=auto_any

and various combinations of the creation commands and I cannot find a setup that 7.0 will accept.
I would like to know if anyone has successfully migrated from an earlier version of ffmpeg to 7.0 and can still get QSV to work. If so, can you please post a complete example of the code that is necessary to create a working hardware device so that QSV accelerated codecs and filters can still be used?

I my machine (old Intel Core i5 3550 with Intel HD Graphics 2500 GPU with Windows 10), even the most simple encoding command: ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=384x216:rate=10:duration=10 -c:v h264_qsv -pix_fmt nv12 test.mp4 in not working with FFmpeg 6.1.1 and with FFmpeg 7.0. With error message: Error creating a MFX session: -9.. With FFmpeg 5.1.2 it's working fine... The issue could be related to Intel GPU Graphics driver version (try updating the driver). What is your CPU model?

It's not the driver.
I stumbled on the answer from some hints in posts elsewhere.
The syntax that worked for years, which I gave above
-init_hw_device qsv:hw,child_device_type=qsv

No longer works, even though I can't find anything in any documenentation that says why.  However, some people said that the child_device_type has to be changed to the pseudo device d3d11va . This got closer, but also doesn't work for me, it spews out huge numbers of errors.  But changing the line to this:
-init_hw_device qsv=qsv,child_device_type=dxva2

does work for me.  In the past I had tried this syntax with ffmpeg 4.4 with only very small amounts of hardware acceleration.  I also tried this on a different Windows 10 system with an Nvidia graphics card, and it does get a little acceleration on decodes with d3d11va. Apparently, something has changed with no warning that I have ever seen (I welcome corrections if this was in fact publicized somewhere) in how you connect to the hardware device, and the hw_auto and auto_all options don't work.
Since the device changes with software and hardware, you may have to experiment with the various interfaces: but hopefully there will be one that works.
It is possible that on some systems one of the other interfaces like vaapi or opencl or vulkan might also work. I'm not sure there is any advantage to this.  Since the taskmanager GPU display tells me that using dxva2 does access hardware acceleration for both decoding and encoding, I'm probably going to stop here now that I have something that works.

I thought it supposed to be: -init_hw_device qsv=hw,child_device_type=dxva2. Intel Media SDK (and oneVPL QSV) support  the usage of Direct3D 9 and Direct3D 11 memory buffers in Windows. According to the table, dxva2 applies Direct3D 9. You may also try using Direct3D 11: child_device_type=d3d11va.
